# Role-based authorization in Blazor WebAssembly .Net5 MsalAuthentication

Tags: c#, authorization, blazor, webassembly, microsoft-identity-platform

My Blazor Web Assembly app is registered in Azure Active Directory (single tenant my organization only).

Groups claim has been added to the token configuration with the optional setting to emit groups as role claims.

I am able to run the app and authenticate, but any page with Authorize attribute defining specific roles within my organization shows the "You are not authorized to access this resource." message configured in App.razor for Not Authorized

I have confirmed that I am receiving the roles Claim, but is a json array of role names.

I have tried creating a custom `AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory` where I deserialize the roles claim value and add a new claim for each role name in the array, but still get the same result.

```
public class CustomAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory : AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount>
{
    public CustomAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory(IAccessTokenProviderAccessor accessor)
        : base(accessor) { }

    public async override ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> CreateUserAsync(RemoteUserAccount account, RemoteAuthenticationUserOptions options)
    {
        var user = await base.CreateUserAsync(account, options);

        if (!user.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            return user;
        }

        if (user.Identity is not ClaimsIdentity identity)
        {
            return user;
        }

        var roleClaims = identity.FindAll("roles");

        if (roleClaims is null || !roleClaims.Any())
        {
            return user;
        }

        foreach (var roleClaim in roleClaims)
        {
            try
            {
                var roleNames = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string[]>(roleClaim.Value);

                foreach (var roleName in roleNames)
                {
                    identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, roleName));
                }
            }
            catch
            {
                // continue
            }
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

And in my Program.cs

```
_ = builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication(options =>
    {
        Configuration.Bind("AzureAD", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add("app-scope");
    })
    .AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<CustomAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory>();
```

And on my page

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
@attribute [Authorize(Roles="GROUP1, GROUP2, GROUP3")]
```

I have confirmed that the `AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory` has added each role as a new claim and I am able to view the user's profile information and get a true response from `user.IsInRole("GROUP1");`, however, on any page with the `[Authorize]` attribute, I still see the same error:

> You are not authorized to access this resource

Am I missing something? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to modify the token configuration to add groups claim using Group ID rather than sAMAcountName, and then use the Group's Object id value in the page's `[Authorize]` attribute and in AuthorizeView components.

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization
[Authorize(Roles="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy, zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz")]
<div>
    <p>Only user's in the "X", "Y", or "Z" role are authorized to view this page</p>
    <AuthorizeView  Roles="xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx, zzzzzzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzz-zzzzzzzzzzzz">
        <p>This content is only rendered for user's in the "X" or "Z" role</p>
    </AuthorizeView>

    <AuthorizeView  Roles="yyyyyyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyy-yyyyyyyyyyyy">
        <p>This content is only rendered for user's in the "Y" role</p>
    </AuthorizeView>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I've bumped into a very closely related issue. My auth provider (in my case I'm using MsalAuthentication) is returning roles with a claim named "roles" rather than the expected "http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role", therefore anything protected with an `Authorize(Roles = "some-role")` would return unauthorized, even if the user has the role.

My solution was to implement my own `AuthenticationStateProvider` and override the `GetAuthenticatedUser` method:

```
public class RoleTransformingAuthenticationStateProvider : RemoteAuthenticationService<RemoteAuthenticationState, RemoteUserAccount, MsalProviderOptions>
{
    public RoleTransformingAuthenticationStateProvider(
        IJSRuntime jsRuntime,
        IOptionsSnapshot<RemoteAuthenticationOptions<MsalProviderOptions>> options,
        NavigationManager navigation,
        AccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteUserAccount> accountClaimsPrincipalFactory)
        : base(jsRuntime, options, navigation, accountClaimsPrincipalFactory)
    {
    }

    protected override async ValueTask<ClaimsPrincipal> GetAuthenticatedUser()
    {
        var user = await base.GetAuthenticatedUser();

        var rolesClaim = user?.FindFirst("roles");

        if (rolesClaim is not null)
        {
            var roleList = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<IEnumerable<string>>(rolesClaim.Value);
            var roles = roleList!.Select(x => new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, x));

            user.AddIdentity(new ClaimsIdentity(roles));
        }

        return user;
    }
}
```

I then added my AuthStateProvider to the services in program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<
    AuthenticationStateProvider,
    RoleTransformingAuthenticationStateProvider>();
```